# SQL Error Code 1055

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer:

```
SELECT NOMBREPILOTO AS PUNTUA, PUNTOS CARRERA AS TOTAL_PTOS_2017
FROM TCOMPITE
WHERE YEAR(FECHA)=2017
GROUP BY NOMBREPILOTO
HAVING SUM(PUNTOSCARRERA)>0
ORDER BY PUNTOS CARRERA DESC;
```

Y me devuelve el error code 1055, no consigo arreglarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En **MySQL** la **cláusula group by** no cumple con el estándar de **SQL**, el cual establece que las columnas que no aparecen en la **cláusula  group by** deben deben aparecer en la **cláusula select** con una **función de agregación**, pero al parecer las versiones más recientes de **MySQL** están tratando de corregir este problema.

En tu ejemplo agrupas por la **columna NombrePiloto**, pero en el **select** la **columna PuntosCarrera** no aparece con una **función de agregación**, tienes dos opciones: hacer tu consulta respetando respetando el estándar **SQL** o actualizando la **variable de entorno de MySQL**, de las 2 opciones la mejor es la primera ya que cumplirías con el estándar de **SQL**, pero tendrías que tener conocimientos un poco "avanzados" para armar esta nueva consulta (en realidad no es tan difícil, pero lleva su tiempo y pensamiento), la segunda opción que es a la que me voy a referir es más fácil de hacer, pero viola el estándar **SQL**(**MySQL** nunca ha respetado este estándar pero parece que los desarrolladores de **MySQL** se están esforzando para que las versiones más recientes lo cumplan).

Por tanto si nos vamos por la segunda opción lo que debes hacer es:

```
SET  sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

La **variable de entorno sql_mode** originalmente vendría con el valor:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```

Este valor es el que haría que se cumpliera con el estándar de **SQL**, y como ves más arriba pues reconfiguramos esta **variable de entorno** quitándole este valor.

Comment: Lo intentaré solucionar, gracias.

Comment: @Soullesito podrias decirme si la respuesta te sirvio, gracias

Comment: Hola, perdona, sí me ha servidor para entender el fallo. Gracias